# how can I divide two str?

Tags: python

when I ran the bellow code;

```
a = input('please enter your weight :')
b = input('please enter your height :')
print(a/b)
```

I got this error:

Type Error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: convert the strings into int then you divide them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a = int(input('please enter your weight :'))
b = int(input('please enter your height :')) 
print(a/b)
```